# Git wants me to merge dev into dev

Tags: git, github, merge

I have been working on a github project for a while now.  On one of my computers, whenever I try to pull my teammates' recent commits to 'dev' branch, it immediately wants me to merge the same exact changes back.  I know this sounds pretty odd, but I am not sure how else to describe it.

For example:

```
Person A makes a commit adding file 'a.txt' and modifying 'b.txt'.
Person A pushes this to branch 'other-branch' and then merges 'other-branch' into 'dev'.
Person A then pushes merge commit as well.
```

Now I go to github, specifically github desktop ui (though, I tested it with git bash and got the same behavior) and it says that I have changes to pull on dev.  So I pull and see that it modified 'a.txt' and 'b.txt' as it should.  And I can see Person A's commits in the commit history.
Then immediately after I pull, it stages changes that are the exact same that I just pulled.  For example, in this case that would be the addition of 'a.txt' and modification of 'b.txt'.

If I try to delete the staged changes, is says that I have to pull again.  But if I pull again, I'm right back where I started.  It makes no sense to me.  The only way I have found to break the cycle is to delete the local repository and re-clone from the point of the commits I am trying to pull.

The commit I see that gets made on github desktop looks something like this:

```
Merge branch 'dev' of https://github.com/<repo owner>/<repo name> into dev
```

I know this is probably a silly question, and there is probably a really simple fix, but I'm starting to lose my mind deleting and cloning the repository over and over.

Also of note, it just seems to be on this computer.  On my other computer, I seem to be able to pull changes from the same repo just fine without any issues.

Edit: When using the github desktop ui, not only with it stage the changes for this merge, it will make the commit for me as soon as I pull.  Also, if it is helpful, I am on windows 10.

Comment: It may be that you have local change/commit before merging so when you are pulling, it is merging to have the two versions in one, could you try either run a `git status` before pulling or creating another local branch and checking it out, to ensure that all modifications goes to this branch and not develop

Comment: Yea, I have tried multiple times.  I can tell you with 100% confidence, my local head has 0 staged changes, 0 commits, and is up to date with the remote besides the data I am pulling.  Regardless of what I do, when I try to pull it.  It makes that merge commit with the same data that I just pulled.  Like making a duplicate of everything.  And as soon as I delete the local and re-clone the remote, I am fine until the next pull.